# Query posts alphabetically within this function

Tags: query, sort

I've been given some code to tidy up and edit a bit and the client wants to organize a custom post type named "plans" alphabetically.

It's not a straight forward query and I've never come across anything like this before, any ideas?

```
<?php $planIDs = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_lm_comm_plans', false); ?>
<?php foreach ($planIDs as $planID) : ?>
    <?php $pdfID = get_post_meta($planID, '_lm_plan_pdf', true); ?>
        <?php $pdfURL = wp_get_attachment_url($pdfID); ?>
            <?php $planTitle = get_the_title($planID); ?>
                <li class="plan"><!-- content here --></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: where does `$planIDs` come from?

Comment: My mistake, I missed a line out. Edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to run through get_posts() to apply the order by handling.

```
$planIDs = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_lm_comm_plans', false );
foreach( get_posts( array( 'post__in' => $planIDs, 'orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC', 'post_type' => 'plans' ) ) as $plan ) {
    $pdfID = get_post_meta( $planID, '_lm_plan_pdf', true );
    $pdfURL = wp_get_attachment_url( $pdfID );
    $planTitle = get_the_title( $planID );
    ?>
    <li class="plan"><!-- content here --></li>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work, the page is completely blank.

Comment: Dean, Sorry, I didn't pay attention the fact that the related plans were another post type.  You just need to make sure the post type is set in the query.  I've updated the code for this.